# Go HTTP server resets connection on multipart form with file and text

Tags: forms, go, multipartform-data, go-http

I've been trying to set up an HTTP server in Go that allows users to upload files via HTML forms. This form would also have a text input for other reasons. However, upon submitting the form, my browser reports the connection has reset (I've tried with Firefox and Chromium), and inspection shows that the server doesn't even get to the handler function of the upload end point before this reset, though it doesn't crash. Strangely, this does not happen when the only inputs in the form are the file and submit.

Here is a minimal reproduction:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func showPage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprint(w,
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload">
        <input type="file" name="file" />
        <input type="text" name="lol" />
        <input type="submit" value="upload" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>`)
}

func uploadHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("yay!")
    fmt.Fprint(w, "yay!")
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", showPage)
    http.HandleFunc("/upload/", uploadHandler)

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Running the above code and submitting a file in the form at `http://localhost:8080/` should show a "yay!" page and print "yay!" on the server's console. Instead, upon submitting a large enough file (very small files don't cause the problem), the connection resets and nothing is printed on the console. [This 5MB audio sample](https://file-examples.com/storage/fe83b11fb06553bbba686e7/2017/11/file_example_MP3_5MG.mp3) is large enough to cause the issue for me.

If the only input in the form is the file, for some reason, everything runs fine.

Comment: Provided code works as expected with 100+ Mb file for me, and with the provided mp3 too.

Comment: I guess it must be an issue on my machine then. Still I'd like to know what might be causing it.

Comment: The program ignores the error returned from ListenAndServe. Change the last line of main to `log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))`

Comment: @CeriseLimón I am aware, however ListenAndServe doesn't return in this circumstance, the server keeps running, so checking for the log is useless. (I've already done it and got nothing)

Comment: A possible cause of "the server doesn't even get to the handler function" is that ListenAndServe failed because another version of server is still running at 8080.  The log.Fatal wll catch that.

Comment: But the server never stops running. If there was anything for log.Fatal to catch, ListenAndServe would need to return, but it never does. Either way, as I said, I've already done it and nothing is logged, which is why I didn't add log.Fatal in the minimal example.

Answer (score 1):

The handler does not read any of the request body.

On return from the handler, the net/http server closes the connection when the size of the unread request body is greater than [262,144](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/b9a08f159d3074ad5921a9d8625b267b64d957bc/src/net/http/server.go#L1106)
 bytes.

The client receives a connection reset while attempting to write the request body.  The client errors out before reading the response.

Fix by reading the request body. Given that you expect a multipart form, a call to [ParseMultipartForm](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request.ParseMultipartForm) is the easiest way to read the request body.

```
func uploadHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if err := r.ParseMultipartForm(65535); err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "bad request", 400)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("yay!")
    fmt.Fprint(w, "yay!")
}
```

Comment: I see. That explains the issue, but how can it be fixed/circumvented? I assume there is a correct way to do it.

Comment: HTTP spec requires that the server read the request body before the response body can be sent.  Proceed to implement the handling of the MultiPartForm upload in the request.

Comment: I was actually doing that when I found this issue. However, since uploadHandler is never even called before the reset, I don't get the chance to parse the form.